# jQuery validation Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label[for=]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I encountered the error "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label[for=]" after upgrading to jQuery 3.1.1 from an old version of jQuery (1.10.2).  I had also upgraded the jQuery.validate plugin to version 1.15.1.

This is similar to other "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label..." types of questions but unique enough to justify its own entry, I believe.  Multiple searches online for this message didn't lead me to the solution I stumbled upon (below).

The error occurs when clicking into any field on the form after selecting a Yes/No value from a dropdown field which alters the UI slightly.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the error was being triggered in the onfocusout of the jQuery validator.  It was caused because the element / field losing focus didn't have an ID (the error message *almost* makes that clear if you think about it hard enough).

The field losing focus was an unimportant trigger (via jQuery class selector) on a relatively simple form.  The field didn't require any validation on its own.

Adding an ID to the field resolved the issue.

An alternative solution would be to make use of the ignore: feature of the jQuery Validation plugin.